# Insert overwrite doesnt updates data in external table

Tags: hive, hiveql

There is one external table in Hive. It has data. When I do insert overwrite it updates files at location which table points. But table data is not updated when executing `select *`.

Comment: Do you have the LOCATION /path/yourupdatedfile clause in the create external table?

Comment: Yes. I am doing insert overwrite on table with itself. I have other schema where after doing insert overwrite I can see updated table. But not with the schema for which I have ask question.

Comment: check which database you are using, try with use <database name> and then try load

Comment: I tried but of no use.

Answer (score 0):

I tried lot but couldn't find answer for this issue. I did my work using alternative method. I am sharing here so that if someone facing same issue, he can use this.

1.
    create table target_table_name like source_table_name;

2.
    insert overwrite table target_table_name partition(partition_column_name) select * from source_table_name;

3.create external table another_table_name like source_table_name stored as file_format_of_source_table location 'location_of_source_table';

4.msck repair table another_table;

5.Then you can drop source_table and rename another_table to source_table_name.